# Numpy array references behaving strangely when inside a for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a Python implementation of Euler's method, using an example from Paul's math notes [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EulersMethod.aspx).

I'm using a n x 3 numpy array to store the results. The goal is to have the t-value in the first column, y in the second, and the value of y' computed using the current row in the third column.

When I did the first problem listed on the page, using only ten iterations, everything behaved exactly as expected. The step size was 0.1, so the values in the first column incremented by 0.1 with each iteration of the for loop.

But now that I've copied the code over and attempted to apply it to problem 3, the first column behaves very strangely. I inputted the step size as 0.01, but for the first ten iterations it increments by 0.1, then after the tenth iteration it appears to reset to zero, *then* uses the expected 0.01, but later on it resets again in a similar fashion.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np

def ex3(t,y):
    return y + (-0.5 * np.exp(t/2) * np.sin(5*t)) + (5 * np.exp(t/2) * np.cos(5*t))

ex3out = np.empty((0,3), float)
# Input the initial conditions and first y' computation
ex3out = np.append(ex1out, np.array([[0,0,ex3(0,0)]]), axis=0)
h = 0.01
n = 500

for i in range(1,n+1):
    # Compute the new t and y values and put in 0 as a dummy y' for now  
    new = np.array([[ex3out[i - 1,0] + h, ex3out[i - 1,1] + h * ex3out[i - 1,2],0]])
    # Append the new row
    ex3out = np.append(ex3out,new,axis=0)
    # Replace the dummy 0 with y' based on the new values
    ex3out[i,2] = ex3(ex3out[i,0],ex3out[i,1])
```

And here are the first several rows of ex3out after running the above code:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        , -1.        ],
       [ 0.1       ,  0.9       ,  5.2608828 ],
       [ 0.2       ,  0.852968  ,  3.37361534],
       [ 0.3       ,  0.8374415 ,  0.6689041 ],
       [ 0.4       ,  0.83983378, -2.25688988],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.85167737, -4.67599317],
       [ 0.6       ,  0.86780837, -5.90918813],
       [ 0.7       ,  0.8851749 , -5.51040903],
       [ 0.8       ,  0.90205891, -3.40904125],
       [ 0.9       ,  0.91757091,  0.031139  ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.93132436,  4.06022317],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  5.        ],
       [ 0.01      ,  0.99      ,  5.98366774],
       [ 0.02      ,  0.95260883,  5.92721107],
       [ 0.03      ,  0.88670415,  5.82942804],
       [ 0.04      ,  0.84413054,  5.74211536],
       [ 0.05      ,  0.81726488,  5.65763415],
       [ 0.06      ,  0.80491744,  5.57481145],
       [ 0.07      ,  0.80871649,  5.4953251 ],
       [ 0.08      ,  0.83007081,  5.42066644],
       [ 0.09      ,  0.8679685 ,  5.34993924],
       [ 0.1       ,  0.9178823 ,  5.2787651 ],
       [ 0.11      ,  0.97192659,  5.19944036],
       [ 0.12      ,  0.05      ,  4.13207859],
       [ 0.13      ,  1.04983668,  4.97466166],
       [ 0.14      ,  1.01188094,  4.76791408],
       [ 0.15      ,  0.94499843,  4.5210138 ],
       [ 0.16      ,  0.90155169,  4.28666725],
       [ 0.17      ,  0.87384122,  4.0575499 ],
       [ 0.18      ,  0.86066555,  3.83286568],
       [ 0.19      ,  0.86366974,  3.61469476],
       [ 0.2       ,  0.88427747,  3.40492482],
       [ 0.21      ,  0.92146789,  3.20302701],
```

I wondered if this might be a floating point issue, so I tried enclosing various parts of the for loop in float() with the same results.

I must've made a typo somewhere, right?

Comment: I believe `ex3out` should have one row after initialization = `(0, t_0, y_0)`. And in cycle you should just calculate `y_1` and `t_1` and append it to `ex3out`.

Comment: Not that it affects your question, but you code would cleaner and faster if you used lists and list append, instead of numpy and its poorly named `np.append`.

Comment: Only typo I found, with a copy-n-paste is the `ex1out`.  Otherwise it runs, and produces a very different array that your display.  Even the first row is suspect, which according to the code is initialed as `[0,0,ex3(0,0)]`.

Comment: Thank you both! Indeed the ex1out was the culprit. It runs fine now. And thanks @hpaulj for your sample code below, saving the numpy array for the final step. I need to remember that numpy arrays are basically just lists of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler loop:

```
ex3out = [[0, 0, ex3(0,0)]]
h = 0.01
n = 50

for i in range(1,n+1):
    # Compute the new t and y values and put in 0 as a dummy y' for now 
    last = ex3out[-1] 
    new = [last[0] + h, last[1] + h * last[2], 0]
    new[2] = ex3(new[0], new[1])
    # Append the new row
    ex3out.append(new)

print(np.array(ex3out))   # for pretty numpy display
```